# Finding elements of an array lying between two values

Tags: python, arrays, intervals, binary-search

Well the question is as follows:

First of all I am coding in Python.
I have an array(Numpy array but if it could be any of help I can change it to a list) of sorted natural numbers, "givenY". I want to find and point to the first and last element in which fall between two specified values `a=Y[i]` and `b=Y[i+1]`. I wrote the code but I believe I did in one of the nastiest possible ways and I am not sure if the code is temporally efficient. So I would be happy if I could get comments or get a suggestion to write it from the scratch. The important things is there are many exceptional situations when there is no element of givenY between `Y[i]` and `Y[i+1]`(which are handled by assigning `-1` to start). My code is:

```
startRes=binSearch(givenY,Y[i]);
endRes=binSearch(givenY,Y[i+1]);        
start=startRes[1]
end=endRes[1];        
if(givenY.size==0 or (givenY.size>0 and givenY[start]<=Y[i])):
    start=startRes[1]+1;
if(endRes[0]):
    end=endRes[1]-1;
if end<start or (givenY.size>0 and (givenY[end]>Y[i+1] or givenY[start]>=Y[i+1])) or givenY[end]<=Y[i]:
    start=-1;
```

```
startRes=binSearch(givenY,a);
endRes=binSearch(givenY,b);        
start=startRes[1]
if startRes[0]:
    start=start+1;
end=endRes[1]-1;
```

And this is the implementation of binSearch:

```
def binSearch(arr,element):
left=0
right=arr.size;
mid=(left+right)/2
while left<right:
    mid=(left+right)/2
    if(arr[mid]<element):
        left=mid+1;
    elif (arr[mid]>element):
        right=mid;
    else: 
        return True,mid;
return False,left;
```

Some simple input and outputs:

For the givenY=[2,5,8,10]:

- a=3,b=4, output: no in between values.(start=-1 in my code)
- a=2,b=5, output: no in between values.(start=-1 in my code)
- a=2,b=9 output: start=1,end=2
- a=1,b=10,output: start=0,end=2
- a=1,b=11,output: start=0,end=3
- a=11,b=12, output: no in between values.(start=-1 in my code)
- a=0,b=2, output: no in between values.(start=-1 in my code)
- a=3,b=3, output: no in between values.(start=-1 in my code)
- a=5,b=5, output: no in between values.(start=-1 in my code)

In the case I am currently working, b is always greater than a.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: What is `givenY`, is it a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand the indices returned. For example, if `givenY` is and empty list, both `start` and `end` will be -1. Also, the code you posted will not handle duplicate values in the list.

Instead of hand-coded binary search you can use the `bisect` module. For details see the API documentation:

1. [Python 3.3 - 8.6. bisect — Array bisection algorithm](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/bisect.html)
2. [Python 2.7.3 - 8.5. bisect — Array bisection algorithm](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/bisect.html)

Below is an implementation that returns `start` and `end` so that the following properties hold:

1. `end-start` equals the number of elements that are between the given bounds.
2. `list[start:end]` returns the slice containing all values between the given bounds.
3. `end-start` equals the number of elements found
4. When no values are found `start==end`.

Code:

```
import unittest

from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right


def find_range(array, a, b):
    start = bisect_right(array,a)
    end = bisect_left(array,b)
    return (start, end)


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    Y = [1, 3, 5, 10, 15]
    givenY = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

    def test_empty_array(self):
        self.assertEqual( (0, 0), find_range([], 1, 2) )

    def test_all_values_larger(self):
        self.assertEqual( (0, 0), find_range([4,5,6], 1, 3) )

    def test_all_values_larger_or_equal(self):
        self.assertEqual( (0, 0), find_range(self.givenY, self.Y[0], self.Y[1]) )

    def test_both_endpoints_inside_list(self):
        self.assertEqual( (1, 2), find_range(self.givenY, self.Y[1], self.Y[2]))
        self.assertEqual( [4], self.givenY[1:2])

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual( (3, 7), find_range(self.givenY, self.Y[2], self.Y[3]) )
        self.assertEqual( [6, 7, 8, 9], self.givenY[3:7])

    def test_no_values_larger_or_equal_to_upper_limit(self):
        self.assertEqual( (8, 9), find_range(self.givenY, self.Y[3], self.Y[4]) )
        self.assertEqual( [11], self.givenY[8:9])


if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

NOTE: The returned start and end positions should easily be adjusted to your current values if needed, just make sure that it is consistent.

**EDIT**

Below is code that returns the values requested, as far as I can understand from the samples given. The logic is described in the `find_range()` docstring. The original code is kept as it IMHO feels more natural when programming in Python.

```
import unittest

from bisect import bisect_left, bisect_right


def find_range(array, a, b):
    """Find elements that are greater than a and less than b.
    Returns a tuple (start,end) where array[start] is the first
    value and array[end] is the last value.
    If no value is found, returns start=end=-1.
    """
    start = bisect_right(array,a)
    end = bisect_left(array,b)
    if start==end:
        return (-1,-1)
    else:
        return (start, end-1)


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    Y = [1, 3, 5, 10, 15]
    givenY = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]

    def test_empty_array(self):
        self.assertEqual( (-1, -1), find_range([], 1, 2) )

    def test_all_values_larger(self):
        self.assertEqual( (-1, -1), find_range([4,5,6], 1, 3) )

    def test_all_values_larger_or_equal(self):
        self.assertEqual( (-1, -1), find_range(self.givenY, self.Y[0], self.Y[1]) )

    def test_both_endpoints_inside_list(self):
        self.assertEqual( (1, 1), find_range(self.givenY, self.Y[1], self.Y[2]))

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual( (3, 6), find_range(self.givenY, self.Y[2], self.Y[3]) )

    def test_no_values_larger_or_equal_to_upper_limit(self):
        self.assertEqual( (8, 8), find_range(self.givenY, self.Y[3], self.Y[4]) )

    def test_sample(self):
        self.assertEqual( (3,3), find_range([1,3,5,7], 5, 8)  )
        self.assertEqual( (3,3), find_range([1,3,5,7], 6, 8)  )


if __name__=="__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time but this code doesn't work:
for givenY=[1,3,5,7] it should return (3,3) but it returns
(3,4) which is even exceeds bound. And as I mentioned earlier, I set start=-1 when there is no givenY value between a and b for later use.

Comment: What are the values for Y[i] and Y[i+1] in this case? Please read the post as I have clearly defined what the return values are. In particular, I state that array[start:end] will return values that are between the bounds. In this particular case, 4 is not outside the bounds, `[1,3,5,7][3:4]` will return `[7]` since the upper bounds points to the first element not to include (similar to iterators in C++). If you could specify the exactly what to return in the different cases, I will modify the code to handle this.

Comment: They are integer values, but that is not important as I said you can replace them with a and b. Thanks a lot but I want end to point to the last element in the interval! I already wrote many input and outputs in my post(at the end of the post)

Comment: I wanted the actual bound values for testing :) I have added one more code block that I expect matches what you originally asked for. Based on the code, the sample outputs and your comments I am not completely sure what the outputs are. Please check my docstring to see if it matches what you need.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Sort the list first, then do a linear search.</strike>

Remove semicolons, they are not needed and not needed...

Comment: Thanks for reminding the list is sorted. Therefore using binary search  seems to be more logical than linear search.
I prefer semi-colons, it reminds me of C and Java but thanks for mentioning!

Comment: Won't a linear search be slower than a binary search?